# How to generate protobuf problem with importing

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I have those 2 protobuf files:

**user.proto**:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message User{
  string name = 1;
  int32 age = 2;
  string email = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 4;
}
```

**API.proto:**

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "user.proto";

service ServerAPI {
  rpc Init(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc Get(User) returns (Result) {}
}

message Result {
  bool result = 1;
}
```

Both of them are in the same dir called `proto_files`:

When I am trying to run `protoc -I=. --dart_out=grpc:build/generated proto_files/*.proto` I am getting the following error message.

```
google/protobuf/empty.proto: File not found.
user.proto: File not found.
proto_files/API.proto:2:1: Import "google/protobuf/empty.proto" was not found or had errors.
proto_files/API.proto:3:1: Import "user.proto" was not found or had errors.
proto_files/API.proto:6:12: "google.protobuf.Empty" is not defined.
proto_files/API.proto:6:44: "google.protobuf.Empty" is not defined.
proto_files/API.proto:7:11: "User" is not defined.
```

But if I am going to remove the dependencies between those 2 files, everything is going to work properly, if I will not use the import anylonger.

Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

`protoc` is very particular that you must fully (and consistently) reference the path(s) to your protos.

Because `proto_files` is used to reference your protos (i.e. `proto_files/*.proto`), `proto_files` must be in the `--proto_path` (`-I`) too.

`protoc` should (!?) include Google's [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf). The binary (`protoc`) is in the `/bin` folder and the Well-Known Types should be in the `/include` folder.

It appears that, on your machine, these aren't being automatically discovered. You can add these directly to the `--proto_path` too but you will need to specify the location.

Try:

```bash
# Replace with path to `protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}` folder
# The `protoc` binary is in `${PROTOC}/bin`
# Google's Well-Known Types should be in `${PROTOC}/include`
PROTOC="..."

protoc \
--proto_path=proto_files \
--proto_path=${PROTOC}/include \
--dart_out=grpc:build/generated \
proto_files/*.proto
```

Comment: it dose not work, I am getting the same error message as before :(

Comment: Curious. Including the `user.proto: File not found.` and `proto_files/API.proto:7:11: "User" is not defined.` errors? I would expect it to continue to error on `google/protobuf/empty.proto` because I forgot to tell you how to solve that (apologies).

Comment: I would like to be the solution... trust me... but nop...

Comment: `google/protobuf/empty.proto: File not found.
google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.
user.proto:2:1: Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
user.proto:8:3: "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.
API.proto:3:1: Import "google/protobuf/empty.proto" was not found or had errors.
API.proto:4:1: Import "user.proto" was not found or had errors.
API.proto:7:12: "google.protobuf.Empty" is not defined.
API.proto:7:44: "google.protobuf.Empty" is not defined.
API.proto:8:11: "User" is not defined.`

Comment: this is the error output that I have after that command

Comment: Then, I can't help. The above works for me.